# precalculus application: area and cost

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> A rectangular piece of land to be developed as a memorial park has an area of $48 \;\mathrm{m}^2$. The length of the lot is three times the width of the lot. A rectangular path whose width is $x$ meters is to be constructed along the inner perimeter of the lot. The land contained within the path will be landscaped. The cost to construct the path is \$2 per square meter and the cost to landscape the inner field is \$3 per square meter. Express the total cost to develop this lot as a function of $x$, the width of the path.

I am in doubt of what the problem meant by the rectangular path. This is what I think of the drawing. Please tell me which is right. If they're both wrong, please help me make it right. Thanks![image]

Answer (score 1):

The first drawing is the correct interpretation.

Comment: Okay. Thanks a lot.